# Hadoop HDFS - Difference between Missing replica and Under replicated blocks

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fsck

I know that both Under-replicated blocks and Mis-replicated blocks occur due to lesser data node count with respect to replication factor set.

But what is the difference between them?

On re-setting replication factor to 1 where available data node is 1, both Under-replicated blocks and Missing replica error got cleared. Ensured this by executing command **hdfs fsck /**
[image: FSCK report]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" by Tom White:

> **Over-replicated blocks**
> These are blocks  that    exceed  their   target  replication for the file    they    belong  to.
> Normally, over-replication    is  not a   problem,    and HDFS    will    automatically   delete  excess
> replicas.
>
> **Under-replicated blocks**
> These are blocks  that    do  not meet    their   target  replication for the file    they    belong  to.
> HDFS  will    automatically   create  new replicas    of  under-replicated    blocks  until   they    meet
> the   target  replication.    You can get information about   the blocks  being   replicated  (or
> waiting   to  be  replicated) using    hdfs   dfsadmin    -metasave .
>
> **Misreplicated   blocks**
> These are blocks  that    do  not satisfy the block   replica placement   policy  (see    Replica
> Placement).   For example,    for a   replication level   of  three   in  a   multirack   cluster,    if  all
> three replicas    of  a   block   are on  the same    rack,   then    the block   is  misreplicated   because
> the   replicas    should  be  spread  across  at  least   two racks   for resilience. HDFS    will
> automatically re-replicate    misreplicated   blocks  so  that    they    satisfy the rack    placement
> policy.
>
> **Corrupt  blocks**
> These are blocks  whose   replicas    are all corrupt.    Blocks  with    at  least   one noncorrupt
> replica   are not reported    as  corrupt;    the namenode    will    replicate   the noncorrupt  replica
> until the target  replication is  met.
>
> **Missing  replicas**
> These are blocks  with    no  replicas    anywhere    in  the cluster.

Hope this answers your question.